# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Food_Founder.Models.OrderDetail' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As the title mentioned, I met this problem recently and I confused on it. How this error occur and why? I have write my code properly and it seems no problem. After I do research on this kind of error, I still not understand.

```
        public ActionResult AddOrder(OrderDetail orderDetail)
        {
            string message = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (myDatabaseEntities1 myDatabase1 = new myDatabaseEntities1())
                {
                    String userid = Convert.ToString(myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.User_ID == orderDetail.User_ID).FirstOrDefault());
                    userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    DateTime CurrentDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var Date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.OrderDate == orderDetail.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault());
                    Date = CurrentDT;
                    Double T_Price = Convert.ToDouble(myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.OrderPrice == orderDetail.OrderPrice).FirstOrDefault());

                    //WF
                    var A_ChickenChop_BP = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_BP == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenChop_M = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_M == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_M).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_AH = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_AH == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_AH).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_P = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_P == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_P).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_S = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_S == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_S).FirstOrDefault();
                    //CF
                    var A_ChickenRice_CB = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_CB == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CB).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenRice_CW = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_CW == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CW).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenRice_D = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_D == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_D).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_WantanMee_NS = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_WantanMee_NS == orderDetail.A_WantanMee_NS).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_WantanMee_IS = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_WantanMee_IS == orderDetail.A_WantanMee_IS).FirstOrDefault();

                    //WF
                    Double PriceOfF1 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenChop_BP) * 14.9;
                    Double PriceOfF2 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenChop_M) * 14.9;
                    Double PriceOfF3 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_AH) * 10.9;
                    Double PriceOfF4 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_P) * 10.9;
                    Double PriceOfF5 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_S) * 10.9;
                    //CF
                    Double PriceOfF6 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_CB) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF7 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_CW) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF8 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_D) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF9 = Convert.ToDouble(A_WantanMee_NS) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF10 = Convert.ToDouble(A_WantanMee_IS) * 6.9;

                    T_Price = PriceOfF1 + PriceOfF2 + PriceOfF3 + PriceOfF4 + PriceOfF5
                        + PriceOfF6 + PriceOfF7 + PriceOfF8 + PriceOfF9 + PriceOfF10;

                    if (T_Price > 1)
                    {
                        myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
                        myDatabase1.SaveChanges();
                        message = "The order has been placed successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Please order any food at least one";
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            return View(orderDetail);
        }
```

The error is occur at the line I make the database data to double. As you can see there is a lot of data I make that are double and all of that have met this problem.
By the way, all of these data in database I make them are int type.

```
        [Display(Name = "Order ID")]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public int User_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order Address")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Address is required for the order")]
        public string OrderAddress { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of ChickenChop in Black Pepper Sauce")]
        public int A_ChickenChop_BP { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of ChickenChop in Mushroom Sauce")]
        public int A_ChickenChop_M { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of Angel Hair Spaghetti")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_AH { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of Penne Spaghetti")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_P { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of Shell Spaghetti")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_S { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of ChickenRice with Chicken Breast part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_CB { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of ChickenRice with Chicken Wing part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_CW { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of ChickenRice with Drumstick part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_D { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of Non-Spicy Wantan Mee")]
        public int A_WantanMee_NS { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount of the food is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Amount Of Spicy Wantan Mee")]
        public int A_WantanMee_IS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Price")]
        public Nullable<int> OrderPrice { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Is the order paid?")]
        public Nullable<bool> Is_Paid { get; set; }
```

Can someone explained to me how this error happened and way to solved it?

And the exact line to met this error are

```
                    Double T_Price = Convert.ToDouble(myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.OrderPrice == orderDetail.OrderPrice).FirstOrDefault());

                    //WF
                    var A_ChickenChop_BP = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_BP == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenChop_M = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_M == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_M).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_AH = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_AH == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_AH).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_P = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_P == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_P).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_Spaghetti_S = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_Spaghetti_S == orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_S).FirstOrDefault();
                    //CF
                    var A_ChickenRice_CB = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_CB == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CB).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenRice_CW = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_CW == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CW).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_ChickenRice_D = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenRice_D == orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_D).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_WantanMee_NS = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_WantanMee_NS == orderDetail.A_WantanMee_NS).FirstOrDefault();
                    var A_WantanMee_IS = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_WantanMee_IS == orderDetail.A_WantanMee_IS).FirstOrDefault();

                    //WF
                    Double PriceOfF1 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenChop_BP) * 14.9;
                    Double PriceOfF2 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenChop_M) * 14.9;
                    Double PriceOfF3 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_AH) * 10.9;
                    Double PriceOfF4 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_P) * 10.9;
                    Double PriceOfF5 = Convert.ToDouble(A_Spaghetti_S) * 10.9;
                    //CF
                    Double PriceOfF6 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_CB) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF7 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_CW) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF8 = Convert.ToDouble(A_ChickenRice_D) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF9 = Convert.ToDouble(A_WantanMee_NS) * 6.9;
                    Double PriceOfF10 = Convert.ToDouble(A_WantanMee_IS) * 6.9;
```

Comment: "The error is occur at the line I make the database data to double." -- this doesn't make sense based on your error message.  Can you show us the exact line where you are getting the error?

Comment: You a trying to convert a Entity from the database to a `double`. You a missing the property holding the `double` value.

Comment: Try change `var A_ChickenChop_BP = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_BP == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP).FirstOrDefault();` to `var A_ChickenChop_BP = myDatabase1.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.A_ChickenChop_BP == orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP).FirstOrDefault()?.A_ChickenChop_BP;`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Why? I mean I use the database data will be realized as double so that I can do the calculation. Is this way cannot to the database? Ya, thanks for remind and I just showed it.

Comment: And be aware that `A_ChickenChop_BP` can be `null`.

Comment: @FrankNielsen So the way you recommend me is to make a property to hold ```double``` value?

Comment: You entity have `int` to hold number of items - which is just fine.

Comment: But you have a lot on `Convert` stuff, that should not be needed. And it seems your approach on finding the `OrderDetail` price is wrong. Why read from the database, when you method already have the `OrderDetail`?

Comment: @FrankNielsen FYI, I'm new in asp.net and c#. All of that code I'm learning from the online and write it and maybe my concept is wrong.

Comment: @FrankNielsen So that I can write like ```OrderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP * 14.9``` like this?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199211/discussion-between-steven-yu-and-frank-nielsen).